# How to update GLIBC_2.17 in CentOS

Tags: centos, glibc, kingsoft

After unpacking the  kingsoft-office_9.1.0.4032~a10_x86.tar, I run the "et", but the terminal telled me that

```
 /king/kingsoft-office_9.1.0.4032~a10_x86/office6/et: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by /king/kingsoft-office_9.1.0.4032~a10_x86/office6/libstdc++.so.6)
```

then follwing the tip, I download the deb from http://community.wps.cn/wiki/Libstdc%2B%2B_too_old, and operated as what the website says, anyway, the same question still occurs

Comment: Since I need a document editor, anyboby tell me a way to install the wps??

Answer (score 0):

I also had to install it on Centos 6.3 just now as it's a dependency of something I needed. I looked on google for glibc_2.17 and centos and found your question. Then I looked for glibc_2.17 and Fedora and found this link `http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/3/srodzaj/1/search/libc.so.6%28GLIBC_2.17%29%2864bit%29`the and RPM for Fedora labeled 'other' which was this `glibc-2.17-4.fc19.src.rpm`. My intent with the link was not any plug, just a reference for the one I downloaded. I clicked on the fedora glibc link and after a few clicks had it in my Download folder.

I did the following and my depencency was resolved.

```
$ sudo user mockbuild
$ sudo groupadd mockbuild
  groupadd: group 'mockbuild' already exists     // I happened to already have it
$ sudo rpm -ivh glibc-2.17-4.fc19.src.rpm 
warning: glibc-2.17-4.fc19.src.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID ba094068: NOKEY
1:glibc                  ########################################### [100%]
```

Hope this helps, it's my first answer on stackoverflow.

Comment: You installed a `.src.rpm`. That contains sources for glibc, not the binaries for glibc that an application like `kingsoftoffice` would be looking for.